# Multipart request body contains input stream before the authentication challenge

Tags: ios, http, alamofire, multipartform-data, http-authentication

Scenario:

- server with Digest authentication
- multipart request to upload a file

I made some packet captures to inspect the work I've made so far and I noticed that when a upload is performed, the first request (before the authentication challenge) already has the input stream appended in its body content. In a protocol POV, the first request should have just the necessary parts to trigger the authentication challenge and once we have the token use it to successfully perform the next one.

Does anyone know why this happens? I tried to a dig a little bit through the lib source code but I did not find my answer.

Thanks a lot.